# XAML image loading for dynamic elements

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Okay so my problem is that I generate some elements on the fly, as linked to an array (for each element on the array there is another item in the XAML). I'm doing this with a TreeView control, albiet following an online example (which has been working well so far).

In this example, the groups are families and within each ... well, it's easier to show in an image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBgS7.jpg). Family is a class which contains an ObservableCollection of FamilyMembers, both of which are used to populate the TreeView.

Here's the main business:

```
<TreeView Name="trvFamilies">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:Family}" ItemsSource="{Binding Members}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{StaticResource ImageGroup}" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" [" Foreground="Blue" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Members.Count}" Foreground="Blue" />
                    <TextBlock Text="]" Foreground="Blue" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:FamilyMember}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{StaticResource ImageUserMale}" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" (" Foreground="Green" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" Foreground="Green" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" years)" Foreground="Green" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

This all works fine, but here's my problem: I have a male image for if a family member is male and a female one for if the family member is female. I don't know how to get at the elements to set the image based on this criterion. As you can see, at the moment the images are static.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `DataTrigger`, e.g. on a potential enum `Gender` property of your FamilyMember:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource ImageUserUnknownGender}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Gender}" Value="Male">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource ImageUserMale}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Gender}" Value="Female">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource ImageUserFemale}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Comment: Well, that'll do it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Note that there are two common alternatives to this approach. First, you could directly bind the Source property of the Image control to a `GenderImage` property of type `ImageSource` in your FamilyMember class. Second, you could bind to the `Gender` property with a Binding Converter, that converts from the Gender enum to ImageSource.